# Inserting text inside an arrow in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to draw an arrow between two nodes (a) and (b), and write text inside the arrow. How can I modify this command to control the size of the arrow head  and insert the text?

```
\draw[->, >=latex, blue!20!white, line width=15pt]   (a) to (b) ;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can perfectly use the shapes library for this. Use `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}`. Based on an example from the TikZ manual, page 441:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={single arrow, draw=none, rotate=60}]
        \node [fill=red!50] {arrow 1};
        \node [fill=blue!50, single arrow head indent=1ex] at (1.5,0) {arrow 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: It is best to post a fully compilable example with a `\documentclass` (can use `article`, unless a reason to use something else), and include all the packages so that others can just cut and paste.

Comment: Thanks, but you should **not** use the `minimal` class. See [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class), that was why I had suggested using the `article` class.

Comment: It still gave the identical output, but I fixed it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah in this case it does not matter, but better **not** to use `minimal` in general.

Answer (score 12):

Those are two quite different questions, answering the one in the title:

If you simply add a `node` along the line, it will be printed on top of the line (unless otherwise specified). You have to change the color though, as the color specification of the `\draw` command also applies to the node.

For non-horizontal arrows add `sloped` to the `node` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (6,0);
\coordinate (c) at (45:6);

\draw[->, >=latex, blue!20!white, line width=15pt] (a) to node[black]{text} (b);
\draw[->, >=latex, blue!20!white, line width=15pt] (a) to node[black,sloped]{text} (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!   I had to specify `anchor=center` for this to work

Comment: Does this also work for arrows that are not horizontal?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Yes, the node placement along the path doesn't depend on the direction of the line. But to get the correction rotation you need to add the `sloped` option to the node. (i.e. `node[black,sloped]{text}`).