# Tikz bug with math in decoration text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58510/inserting-text-inside-an-arrow-in-tikz), I write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    decorations.text,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (6,0);
\draw[->, >=latex, blue!20!white, bend left=20, line width=15pt] (a) to (b) ;
\draw [bend left=20, decoration={raise=-0.8ex,text along path, text={{$start$}.}, text align={align=left}}, decorate] (a) to (b);
\draw [bend left=20, decoration={raise=-0.8ex,text along path, text={{$end\qquad$}.}, text align={align=right}}, decorate] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But, if I remove the "." characters, latex either repeats the text forever or else goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Which "." are you referring to?

Comment: The ones in: `{{$start$}.}` and `{{$end$}.}`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the words start and end. Do you want them in italics?

Comment: @azetina: No, they're actually macros in my code, which expand to bolded greek symbols.  I'm finding this hard to read though, and investigating other options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of your `.` use an empty pair of `{}`.

Instead of that `\qquad` hack I present

```
text align/right indent=1cm
```

That, sadly, does not work with `em` units …

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (6,0);
\draw[->, >=latex, blue!20!white, bend left=20, line width=15pt] (a) to (b) ;
\draw [name=reusepath,bend left=20, decoration={raise=-0.8ex,text along path, text={{$start$}{}}}, decorate] (a) to (b);
\draw [bend left=20, decoration={raise=-0.8ex,text along path, text={{$end$}}, text align/right indent=1cm, text align=right}, decorate] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### From the `beamer` manual

> It is only possible to typeset text in math mode under considerable restrictions. Math mode is entered and exited using any character of category code 3 (e.g., in plain TeX this is `$`). Math subscripts and superscripts need to be contained within braces (e.g., `{^y_i}`) as do commands like `\times` or `\cdot`. However, even modestly complex mathematical typesetting is unlikely to be successful along a path (or even desirable).

---

### Update

I allowed myself to "clean" your code a little bit, so that only one path is generated and the decorations are declared as a postaction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (6,0);
\draw[->, >=latex,
      blue!20!white,
      bend left=20,
      line width=15pt,
      postaction={decorate,decoration={
          raise=-0.8ex,
          text along path,
          text={{$start$}{}}
        }
      },
      postaction={decorate,decoration={
          raise=-0.8ex,
          text along path,
          text={{$end$}},
          text align/right indent=1cm,
          text align=right
        }
      }
  ] (a) to (b) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the cleaned code!

Comment: @NeilG While the indention is for the humans to be able to read the code easier, the implementation with `postaction` is easier to maintain, because you only have to change one path, not three, when you want a different path.

Comment: Excellent point.  In my case, I'm actually generating all of the tikz code using Python, so it's not so bad :)